# Filter data imported from Excel File to DataGrid

Tags: excel, vb.net, filter, datagrid

```
Dim FileLoc As String = TxtFileLoc.Text
Dim ConStr As String '= String.Empty
If FileLoc.EndsWith(".xls") Then
    ConStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;" & "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", FileLoc)
Else
    ConStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;" & "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", FileLoc)
End If
Dim Cmd As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" & ComboSheets.Text & "" & "]", ConStr)
Cmd.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Table")
Dim dt As New DataSet
Cmd.Fill(dt)
ExlDisp.DataSource = dt.Tables(0)
```

**SAMPLE DATA IN EXCEL SHEET**

```
| SNO      | COURSE   | | ROLL NO  | NAME        | 
| -------- | -------- | | -------- | --------    |
| 1        | CZP      | | 10985    | MARK ANTONY |
| -------- | -------- | | -------- | --------    |
| 2        | CZP      | | 98651    | ANTONY G    |
| -------- | -------- | | -------- | --------    |
| 3        | CZP      | | 98666    | G PRAKASH   |
```

**FILTER DATA BY NAME CONTAINING "ANTONY" AFTER LOADING TO DATAGRID**

FILTER DATA BY NAME (FROM TextBox-TxtFilterName) CONTAINING "ANTONY" AFTER LOADING TO DATAGRID

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? What exactly do you not understand about the information you found when you made the effort to find it?

Comment: Why name a variable `dt` when it refers to a `DataSet`? It should be pretty obvious that `dt` is an appropriate name for a variable of type `DataTable` but you should be using `ds` for a variable of type `DataSet`. That said, why are you creating a `DataSet` at all? If you only need a `DataTable` then just create a `DataTable`. Then you can reasonably use `dt` as the variable name.

Comment: [For nearly all purposes, you should use the DataGridView control.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/differences-between-the-windows-forms-datagridview-and-datagrid-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)